# firefox/safari/ie top margin ,left margin 0

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

if i use

```
<BODY TOPMARGIN=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 MARGINWIDTH=0>
```

tag like this, will this ensure element i put in my html will displayed the same across all browser? the reason i asking this is because, i was told Internet explorer renedering of the page is slightly different .In other words, if i put img tag in a page and render it on Internet exploerer and render on firefox, maybe the coordinate of the img will slightly different because of margin/page border

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't HTML. It is a combination of obsolete propriety Netscapisms and obsolete propriety Microsoftisms.

If you want to remove the default spacing around a document add:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

… to your [stylesheet](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/27-css-basics/).

That said, a leading cause of differences between browser renderings is [poor choice of Doctypes](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/14-choosing-the-right-doctype-for-your/#doctypeswitching). Also, given the question, you might not be aware of the useful QA tool: [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: does that mean if i use doctype, i no need to put the above code margin0,padding0?

Comment: Doctypes must be the very first thing in the document. Setting the margin and padding must be done in the stylesheet, I linked to a tutorial about using stylesheets above.